# Wordpress: Page not found - Permalink postname

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, server, http-status-code-404

This is a frequently asked question, but after searching for hours I couldn't find any solution that worked for me. So, here's my problem:

When I change my permalinks setting to 'postname' I get a 404 Error when I navigate to a page. I works with the default setting and when I put `index.php` before 'postname' (like this: `http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/%postname%`). But this is pretty ugly and bad for SEO.

My local wordpress installation is here: `/var/www/html/wordpress/`, so I can reach the wordpress homepage at `http://localhost/wordpress/index.php`

I'm running Debian Jessie and WordPress 4.5.3

This is my htacces file automatically created by Wordpress (`/var/www/html/wordpress/.htaccess`). Permission are set to 664.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The Apache Rewrite module is enabled (`sudo a2enmod rewrite`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**EDIT**
In your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` change

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: doesn't work and after saving the permalinks settings, wordpress resets it

Comment: I see that you have updated your htaccess file. Try the below : `code` # BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]

# END WordPress`code`

Comment: Btw, Are you sure that Mod_rewrite is enabled in your system?

Comment: It didn't change anything and Wordpress resets it again, when i save the settings

Comment: `sudo a2enmod rewrite` returns `Module rewrite already enabled`

Comment: Is it possible for you to PM me your admin and ftp access to me, so that I can check the issue?

Comment: # Did you reboot Apache after enabling mod_rewrite?

# remove the <IfModule>...</IfModule> tags and try running WordPress - if you get a 500 Server Error, mod_rewrite isn't installed.

# Are you using LAMP or XAMPP on Localhost?

Comment: It's the same error as before (404) - yes, i rebooted Apache

Comment: Do you use skype or teamviewer?

Comment: Neither of them, anyway I'm not english, so my spoken english is terrible :)

Comment: Did you restarted apache after enabling mod_rewrite?

Comment: Yes, as I said above

Comment: Have you tried Settings --> Permalinks --> Setting them back to "default" or "date", saving it, then going back and checking "postname" then saving again?

Comment: What is the value of AllowOverride in your apache conf file?

Comment: Where is that file?

Comment: Are you using lamp or xamp?

Comment: If you are in LAMP check these two files : /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf
 - /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: `<Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>`
And it works... Thank you so much :)

Comment: The pleasure is all mine. No problem is silly :) Enjoy